# Generation of a video with several images with jcodec

Tags: java, jcodec

I'm using the last 0.2.5 version of jcodec to generate a video with several images. I'm doing this:

```
AWTSequenceEncoder encoder = AWTSequenceEncoder.createSequenceEncoder(file, 25);
```

Then for each image:

```
encoder.encodeImage(image);
```

The when I'm finished:

```
encoder.finish();
```

This return a corresponding video file, without any exception, and I see correctly the first image in VLC, for example, but it seems that the duration of the video is 0. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's better to ask at https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake, I did recreate the `AWTSequenceEncoder`  each time I added an image.